# . How does the mail server detect whether the outbound e-mail is submitted programmatically or manual?

Tags: .net, email

i am using smtp.live.com for sending emails in .net application.
Live SMTP temporarily blocks the account after sending few e-mails through the service

How does the mail server detect whether the outbound e-mail is submitted programmatically or manual?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

What probably happens is that you are sending many emails in a very short time period causing an automatic throttling setup by live.com.

I suggest reading the email terms and conditions.

Comment: is there any settings to allow sending programmatically

Comment: @Srinivas Sabbani - you will need to talk to live.com email services directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its is not the way you submit but the times you send messages. The sending frequency. Some servers block the account if you try to send too many messages in a short time.

Comment: i am using this logic in one survey. so definatly there should be a chance to send mails in short time. any work around for this or any settings we can do in live.com mail